# How can one check if virtual address belongs to user or kernel memory? (and other address properties)

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, x86-64

Suppose I have an error like

```
Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address ffff8000789abcde
```

How can I figure out if this address belongs to user-mode memory area or kernel mode?
If this is kernel, is there a way to recognize that this address is under swap, or uninitialized memory or whatever (what other characteristics / properties of addresses exist?)?

Interesting post: [Five-level page tables](https://lwn.net/Articles/717293/)

Comment: For most if not all current OSes, bit 63 of the address tells you if it is kernel memory.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/509607/64699

Comment: OS use variable TASK_SIZE in kernel , if addr > TASK_SIZE it is kernel space

Comment: *"is there a way to recognize that this address is under swap, or uninitialized memory or whatever"* - if you get to such a point, it means that the address is invalid and does not refer to any existing memory page (swapped or not). The kernel has done anything it could and decided that there isn't anything else to do except die.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Okay, but how can I figure out, what happened? You mean that `Unable to handle kernel paging request` traces are not indicative? One should not investigate it?

Comment: @NK-cell oh, no sorry that's not what I meant. Of course if something like this happens then there's a bug somewhere. You should see a stack trace in dmesg done when the kernel panics. If you don't see any trace then that's peculiar. The address alone does not really give you any information about what actually happened.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Unfortunately the stack traces are not indicative because they are different in case of `Unable to handle kernel paging request`. Some memory is corrupted, it can affect both kernel-mode and user-mode different processes.